# No me funciona el gestor de paquetes Yarn

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarn

No me funciona o no logro inicializar el gestor de paquetes de Yarn, estoy aprendiendo React.js con un profesor y hoy iba a crear una app usando el entorno de Node.js con la documentación oficial de React (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) el profesor indico que lo hiciésemos con el gestor de paquetes de Yarn, los pasos que el explico fueron los siguientes:

1. Instalar Node.js
2. Corroborar que se ha instalado node correctamente con el comando `node-v` y también el npm con `npm -v`
3. Una vez corroborado esto instalar Yarn mediante `npm install --global yarn`
4. Con esto instalado crear la aplicación de React usando  `npx create-react-app my-app` (Aquí es donde tengo el problema)

Captura de la terminal del profesor: (https://prnt.sc/Jeveg__qL7Wr)

En el caso del profesor se puede observar como todas las depedencias se le instalan muy rapido y además en un apartado aparece ***yarn add v.1.22.11*** (https://prnt.sc/2rKIkya6oqd0)

Y en mi caso me sale de la manera común, como saldría normalmente solo usando npm cargando paquete por paquete y se demora unos 7 u 8 minutos (Mientras que al profesor demoro nada mas 1) descargando las dependencias así que por eso creo que no esta haciendo uso de yarn.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Hay alguna forma para habilitar yarn para que cuando use el comando `npx create-react-app my-app` me haga el proceso pero con yarn y no con npm? Gracias de antemano por si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Además de tu consulta, abajo con respuesta. Tomar en cuenta que la primera vez que creas tu aplicación react, baja sin duda casi todos los paquetes, seguro que tu profesor ya los tenía previamente instalados, y por eso solo verifica versiones y si están instalados..... es decir no tarda nada comparando con tu instalación inicial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn es un package manager al igual que npm, y npx es una versión especial de npm.

así que son intercambiables, pero con sintaxis ligeramente diferente.

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

cuyo equivalente con npm es:

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

Comment: Disculpe es que ahí es donde no entiendo que pueda estar pasando, veo que a todo el mundo a la hora de usar "npx create-react-app my-app" le añade el yarn automaticamente utilizando justamente "npx create" y no "yarn create"

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta si me funciono sin problemas, gracias no sabia que existía esta forma de hacerlo.